# How to Compile Single C file in Vim using Makefile Generated by Autotools

Tags: c, vim, makefile, autotools, automake

If in my Makefile.am, I have a set of hypothetically named sources:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libmy_tutorial.la                                           
libmy_tutorial_la_SOURCES = \                                                 
  jump_table.h jump_table.c \                                                  
  core.h core.c \                                                
  my_dynapi.c                                                                   

bin_PROGRAMS = main                                                            
main_SOURCES = main.c                                                          
main_LDADD = libmy_tutorial.la                                     

CLEANFILES = *.o
```

and I am in Vim. Is there a way to call `:make` on a single target if my Makefile is generated from the Makefile.am above.

For example:

`:make main.o`

would compile only main.c from bin_PROGRAMS?

Just as if I had run:

`gcc -c -o main.o $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) main.c`

Comment: I'm confused. What is the question here?

Comment: @FDinoff I apologize. I want to make changes to a file. Then type `:make` in vim and have only that file compiled. This way I can test for syntactical errors as I write a given module. If my project has several include directories and defines that are specified in my Makefile I would like them to apply to this "Single File Compilation". Please let me know what is not clear so I can make it more clear in my question.

Comment: Does `:make main.o` not work? Or do you want something more automatic? Something like `:set makeprg=make\ %<.o` would probably work.

Comment: @FDinoff Since my Makefile is generated by automake I get `make: *** No rule to make target 'main.o'.  Stop.`, when running `:make main.o` within vim. I am assuming this is because there is no explicit rule in the auto generated Makefile. If I run `:make` that builds all object files, and does the linking etc (aka full build). Using `:set makeprg` might work but I would have to switch it back to its default if I wanted to do a `make all`?

Comment: Did you generate the makefile first? You might like to generate that first, if not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Libtool, your targets are `.lo` files instead of `.o` files. Call `make main.lo`, or `make libmy_tutorial_la-main.lo` if you're using per-target `CFLAGS`.